# FlexUnit runner is slow

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexunit4

I have an Air app containing a FlexUnit runner that performs a series of tests on a library project.

Problem is that it takes several minutes (5-10 minutes!) to complete ~1400 tests, of which there are barely any async tasks, and majority of them are not too CPU-heavy.

I've tried running the same test in a repeated cycle and saw that sometimes it's about ~20ms and sometimes it skyrockets to over 5-6 seconds, with the same test conditions.

My guess is it's some sort of internal issue with the runner. I'm curious though whether it's possible to speed it up somehow?

I've already tried upgrading to the latest FlexUnit library.

Comment: What FU listeners do you use? Only CI and trace? Or..?

Comment: it's `XMLListener`, `TraceListener`, `UIListener` and `UnitTestResultListener`. But I tried removing the UI listener and it didn't help.